# Differentiate a list between human names and company names

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of companies, but some of these companies are simply names of people. I want to eliminate these people from the list, but I am having trouble finding a way to identify the names of people from the companies.

Through online research I have tried two ways. The first is using the `nltk`. My code looks like

```
y = ['INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC', 'PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B', 'S J SMITH CO INC', 'TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC', 'KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC', 'JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT', 'ROBERTSON KEITH', 'LINCARE INC', 'AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND']
```

In the above list I would want to remove `PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B`, `JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT`, and `ROBERTSON KEITH`.

```
z = []
for company in y:
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(company)
    z.append(nltk.pos_tag(tokens))
```

This does not work because it tags everything as a proper noun. I then lowercased everything and only made the first letter of each word uppercase using the `.title()`, but this also failed for similar reasons.

The other method I tried was using the `Human Name Parser` module, but this also did not work because it tags the company names as the first and last name of the person.

Is there a way that I can differentiate the above list between human names and company names?

Comment: is that a list? if so you are missing some commas and your quotes are out of wack

Comment: Sounds more like a machine learning problem. How do you expect NLTK to know the definition of a "company"? You'd have to tell it (INC, LLC, CO, GROUP) are all keywords

Comment: My fault I made it a proper list.

Comment: Machine learning? Unfortunate to hear, I know nothing about machine learning and I've heard there is a large learning curve. :(

Comment: Yup, sorry. NLTK is good for phrases and words and such, but you need additional logic to apply any decision making against that data

Comment: This will never work 100% with random data. There are company names that are indistinguishable from people names. For example, I recently bought a shirt from a company named "Tori Richards".  Given the name "Alice Marina", is that the name of a person named "Alice" with a last name of "Marina", or  business named "Alice Marina" that provides a place to store your boat?

Comment: I think it seems like a word sense ambiguation problem

Comment: @cricket_007 actually, nltk knows about companies. tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize("INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC".title())   nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)    namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)   print(namedEnt)  will display S (GPE Inovatia/NNP) (ORGANIZATION Laboratories/NNPS Llc/NNP))

Comment: @psoucy Your comment code is difficult to read. You are more than welcome to provide an answer, though

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry about the format, know no way to format code in a comment. I don't post as an answer because it will not solve the problem. NLTK in general (and named entity recognition even more) will work best with free text, not so well with short phrases like that.

Comment: 3 years later, and none of these answers even got a point? Well, I found them useful, so I gave them each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this entirely programatically, so some manual operation will be needed.  However, you can make things a little easier with `itertools.groupby`

As pointed out in some comments, companies are likely to contain certain keywords, so we can create a list of these to use:

```
key_words = ["INC", "LLC", "CO", "GROUP"]
```

From here, we can sort the list by whether or not an item contains one of those key words (this is necessary to group):

```
y.sort(key=lambda name: any(key_word in name for key_word in key_words))
```

In your example, this will list

```
['PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B', 'JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT', 'ROBERTSON KEITH', 'AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND', 'INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC', 'S J SMITH CO INC', 'TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC', 'KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC', 'LINCARE INC']
```

From here, we can group into things that are *probably* not companies (those which dont contain any key words) and things which are definitely companies (those that do contain key words):

```
import itertools
I = itertools.groupby(y, lambda name: any(key_word in name for key_word in key_words))
```

So we now have two groups:

```
for i in I:
    print i[0], list(i[1])
False ['PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B', 'JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT', 'ROBERTSON KEITH', 'AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND']
True ['INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC', 'S J SMITH CO INC', 'TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC', 'KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC', 'LINCARE INC']
```

You can then manually sort through the false group and remove companies, or apply another similar filter method to further improve the matching.  Some other filters to apply:

- Anything which contains `"MR", "MS", "MRS", "PHD", "DR"` is pretty likely to be a person
- Words of the form `"multiple_letters<space>single_letter<space>multiple_letters"` are probably names, you can do this matching with `re`

Comment: Error on line with sort function `TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function`

Comment: Fixed the error by adding `key = lambda`, but the sort function doesn't seem to sort probably in this case. It creates groups of the `key_words` to sort by, but doesn't create one big group for each.

Comment: @Jstuff, fixed the typo.  Not sure I understand your question though, what do you mean by "sort probably".  When I run the code, I get the output shown in the answer

Comment: Indeed, unless using a machine learning approach this seems like a strong enough heuristic, especially if you don't need really precise output.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you need to differentiate the company and human names. I guess the companies in your list end with either **LLC**, **INC** or contains a **-** (hyphen), thus I made a set of these words `company_set` as `{'LLC', 'INC', '-'}` and then split it into tokens via base function `split()`. If a intersection of `company_set` and splited tokens have anything in common then it will not an empty set, hence company message is printed otherwise human's message. Below is the code:

```
y = ['INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC', 'PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B', 'S J SMITH CO INC', 'TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC', 'KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC', 'JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT', 'ROBERTSON KEITH', 'LINCARE INC', 'AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND']
company_set = {'LLC', 'INC', '-'}
for item in y:
    tokens = set(item.split())
    if company_set.intersection(tokens) !=  set():
        print "{} is a company".format(item)
    else:
        print "{} is a human".format(item)
```

And it outputs as follows:

```
INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC is a company
PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B is a human
S J SMITH CO INC is a company
TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC is a company
KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC is a company
JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT is a human
ROBERTSON KEITH is a human
LINCARE INC is a company
AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND is a company
```

Comment: `if item.endswith(' LLC') or item.endswith(' INC'):`

Comment: If you have a human with the last name "Inc", this will fail.  Unusual, but not impossible.

Comment: Interesting approach, but not all my companies will end with a LLC, INC, etc. I have quite a large list of companies.

Comment: I re-answered your question.

Comment: In General, We sould also add Numbers & Symbols [except . and ,] as they can't occur in Names

Answer (score 1):

Test the list elements for indicators of company names. For your list, this is INC, LLC, and the hyphen (which could be part of a person's name). Or parts of company names (lab, pharma, solutions, ..). There may be other criteria (syllables, phonetics).
Otherwise, you'd need a dictionary of names or companys to test.

```
y = ['INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC', 'PRULLAGE PHD JOSEPH B', 'S J SMITH CO INC', 'TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC', 'KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC', 'JOSEPH D WAGENKNECHT', 'ROBERTSON KEITH', 'LINCARE INC', 'AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND']
f = ["INC", "LLC", "-"]
c = []
for n in y:
  for t in f:
    if t in n:
      c.append(n)
print( "\n".join(c) )
```

gives

```
> t
INOVATIA LABORATORIES LLC
S J SMITH CO INC
TEVA PHARMACEUTICALS USA INC
KENT NUTRITION GROUP INC
LINCARE INC
AGCHOICE - BLUE MOUND
```